# Boost Deadline Timer Runtime Abort Call Issue

Tags: c++, tcp, timer, boost-asio

I have two objects A and B. A uses B underneath, which is a tcp client object. Object B is created in a separate thread in object A's constructor. Within the constructor for B, I use Boost Asio for socket and a deadline timer. I used async calls for the socket connect and the wait on the timer. Here is the code for object B's constructor:

```
B::B(const boost::asio::ip::address& ipaddr, 
                                     std::uint16_t port) : io_service_(),
                                                           socket_(io_service_), 
                                                           endpoint_(ipaddr, port),
                                                           connected_(false) {
    boost::asio::deadline_timer dt(io_service_);
    socket_.async_connect(endpoint_, [this, &dt](const boost::system::error_code& ec) {
        if (ec) {
            std::cout << ec.message() << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            dt.cancel();
            std::cout << "Connected before timer expired" << std::endl;
            connected_ = true;
            socket_.set_option(boost::asio::socket_base::keep_alive(true));
        }
    });
    dt.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(3));
    dt.async_wait([this](const boost::system::error_code& ec) {
        if (ec) {
            std::cout << ec.message() << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Timer expired before connection" << std::endl;
            io_service_.stop();
        }
    });
    io_service_.run();
}
```

When the machine the tcp client wants to connect to is in the ON state, it works. When the machine is in the OFF state, the expectation is that the deadline timer will expire in 3 seconds and the connection flag will not be set. I am getting an abort call during execution. I am sure it is something with the deadline timer, but cannot pin down exactly what.

Does anyone see what may be wrong here or have any other suggestions? Is there something I am missing with Boost Deadline Timer?

Comment: Just a stab in the dark, have you tried `socket_.close()` instead of `io_service_.stop()` in the timer's handler?

Comment: @Chad , for my own edification, please explain why I would do that thanks.

Comment: @Chad, I tried it and got the same abort call issue. I will continue to explore solutions.

Comment: What does it mean to "get an abort call during execution"?

If you mean `std::terminate` or `::abort` are being called, that means your error is somewhere else. Like, maybe the thread that `A` creates to instantiate `B` on is not correctly joined or detached?

Comment: You can easily eliminate other sources of error by just putting that constructor body inside `main()` of a standalone program and testing that _it_ works.

Comment: @xBACP the reason to call `socket_.close()` is it will cancel the async connection attempt and allow the `io_service::run()` call to complete normally.